# Linux SUID config cause binary file fail to execute

Tags: linux, suid

I have one binary file (name is bmu) which needs root privilege while invoking statfs function.

The OS is `SuSE Linux 2.6.16.60-0.21-smp`
The user is test which is to run bmu and is a non-root user

```
test@SuSE:~> id
uid=1056(test) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),16(dialout),33(video)
```

I have tested 3 kinds of scenarios.

--->scenario 1
If bmu is not configured SUID, bmu can be executed but invoking will fail.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 test root 14389879 2012-04-10 10:38 bmu
```

--->scenario 2
If bmu is configured SUID, when bmu run by test, it will fail with the prompt "DBMS API Library 'libclntsh.so' loading fails"

```
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 14389879 2012-04-10 10:38 bmu
```

--->scenario 3
If bmu run by root, it will be executed successfully. of course, no matter SUID is configured or not.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14389879 2012-04-10 10:38 bmu

-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 14389879 2012-04-10 10:38 bmu
```

From scenario 2, it looks like the issue of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` config, but from scenario 1, we can find that this should not the issue of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` config. From scenario 3, we can find that bmu is executable by root.

Only scenario 2 has the problem, so somebody can give some suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When a program is run as setuid, the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable in your environment is ignored because it is a potential security vulnerability.

You should link your binary using an `$ORIGIN` relative rpath to the dependent library, or an absolute rpath reference to the library. See the [ld man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) for details on the $ORIGIN rpath.

Comment: very accurate and useful answer! thank you Petesh! I add required lib path to ld.so.conf and the program works well. I make a simple description on the operation: 1. logon system by root; 2. add the required lib path to /etc/ld.so.conf; 3. run ldconfig command; 4. su - test; 5. run the binary file configured SUID to check the result: OK!

Comment: Adding the library path to the /etc/ld.so.conf is also a valid alternative